# Google Script reading from json object

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps

I am reading a json object such as this:

```
var url = "not really important"
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {'muteHttpExceptions': true});
var json = response.getContentText();
var data = JSON.parse(json);
var var seeds = data.entities.seeds;
```

Now the seeds have the values, ton of them so I know that all my code works up until this point. Now my problem is parsing a certain piece of the information that I need. In this specific case I need to get the name of each entrant. Each seed has a 1:1 ratio with an entrant and as such I have to naviagte this API to get it.

If I run the following code `Logger.log(seeds[0].mutations.entrants);` I will get the following output:

> {745803={isPlaceholder=null, name=My Team Name, participantIds=[827364, 827540, 827994], initialSeedNum=1, id=745803, playerIds={827364=179632, 827540=139681, 827994=268019}}}

As you can see the `name` is under object called `745803`. My problem is that that object name changes and I have no idea what it is for each seed. As such, I need to grab the very first result that is listed under entrants as it will always be the entrant that I need. How can I do this?  I tried the following but it just comes back as undefined:

`seeds[0].mutations.entrants[0].name`

Bottom line is, how do I get the first element in the json based object without knowing the name of that element?

Answer (score 1):

You can retrieve JSON keys using "for in". In this case, you can retrieve it even if the keys are changed. Although I don't know the detailed information of your JSON structure, from your question, following 2 patterns are thought.

**Pattern 1 :**

```
var json1 = {
  "entrants": {
    "745803": {
      "isPlaceholder": null,
      "name": "My Team Name",
      "participantIds": [
        827364,
        827540,
        827994
      ],
      "initialSeedNum": 1,
      "id": 745803,
      "playerIds": {
        "827364": 179632,
        "827540": 139681,
        "827994": 268019
      }
    }
  }
};
for (var i in json1.entrants){
  Logger.log(json1.entrants[i].name)
}

>>> My Team Name
```

**Pattern 2 :**

```
var json2 = {
  "entrants": [
    {
      "745803": {
        "isPlaceholder": null,
        "name": "My Team Name",
        "participantIds": [
          827364,
          827540,
          827994
        ],
        "initialSeedNum": 1,
        "id": 745803,
        "playerIds": {
          "827364": 179632,
          "827540": 139681,
          "827994": 268019
        }
      }
    }
  ]
};
for (var i in json2.entrants){
  for (var j in json2.entrants[i]){
    Logger.log(json2.entrants[i][j].name)
  }
}

>>> My Team Name
```

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.

Comment: I ended up finding a different solution, `json[Object.key(json)[0]];` The Object.key return the actually key value of the object so I am able to use `array['key']` to find my item.

Comment: @Bojan I'm sorry I couldn't be helpful for you.